# sed command with double quotes and regex

Tags: sed

I need to substitute variable $DS_KEY with the variable value. This works but the regex(.*) is not being recognized. The regex works if single qoute is there but then the variable substitution doesn't work. Any pointers ?

```
sed -i "s/DS_PROP_KEYS :=.*/DS_PROP_KEYS := ds_props $DS_KEY/"
```

Sample on which this can be applied:

```
DS_PROP_KEYS := ds_props ('X1', 'X2', 'X3');
```

Comment: please add a sample input line so that it can be tested

Comment: this works for me: `a='XYZ'; echo 'DS_PROP_KEYS := ds_props ('X1', 'X2', 'X3');' | sed "s/DS_PROP_KEYS :=.*/DS_PROP_KEYS := ds_props $a/"`